# How can I find out a wifi password?

Tags: wireless

How can I find out a wifi password if the wifi password has changed? Can I find out wifi passwords using Terminal?

Comment: If you have setup the password and forgot, you can easily check Network Connection in Dash and then go for your connection name => Edit=> Wifi-Security and click on show password.

Comment: Please clarify your question if you asking for something else.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 14.04 you can find your wifi password in the file:

```
sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YOUR-SSID
```

Under the `[802-11-wireless-security]` section:

```
key-mgmt=TYPE
psk=YOUR_wifi_PASSWORD
```

reference: [post #4](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1856435&p=11321721#post11321721) by 
[thefasterblueone](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=773330)